# Combine matching product fields and separate each with | for product variation images

Tags: excel, woocommerce, excel-formula

I have a long list of filenames of images which will need to be used to loop through to import a large number of products into a website.

Each product has several colour variations and different angles of the product for example front, back and side view.

Currently there is 1 filename per row in an excel spreadsheet.

The typical filename is something like as follows: 018M-BLK-FRONT.jpg

The filename consists of SKU-COLOUR-VIEW.jpg.

This particular product has 3 images, 1 for the front, 1 for the back and another for the left side as follows:

```
018M-BLK-BACK.jpg
018M-BLK-FRONT.jpg
018M-BLK-LEFT.jpg
```

I want to have all the images for each SKU and colour variation on the same row separated by a | to look like this:

```
018M-BLK-BACK.jpg|018M-BLK-FRONT.jpg|018M-BLK-LEFT.jpg
```

To clarify the sku section of the filenames are of varying lengths ranging from 3-8 characters, however the colour code section is always 3 characters and they are always seperated by a hyphen (-) as sper the example product provided above. There are a large number of views, but most products have 3 views.

I have tried doing it manually but as I have so many products it will probably take me a week to do it this way.

Comment: What version do you have?  Does it have TEXTJOIN()?  If not then you will need vba

Comment: @ScottCraner I have Excel mac2011 and no it does not have TEXTJOIN() function

Comment: Then you will want VBA , that will iterate the rows and combine the matches into a unique list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is some VBA code that I have written (in Excel 365 for Windows) that should work for you.

It loads all of the images listed into an array, and then loops this array seeing whether the SKU/Colour part already exist in the output array. If they do, then add it to that element, otherwise, add a new pair of elements, consisting of the SKU/Colour part, and the file name. Finally, this output array is written back to the worksheet. I've arbitrarily decided that the size of the output array is 5000, although you may want to increase or decrease it.

```
Sub sJoinImages()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim lngLoop1 As Long
    Dim lngLoop2 As Long
    Dim aInData() As Variant
    Dim aOutData(1 To 5000, 1 To 2) As String
    Dim strDummy As String
    Dim blnFound As Boolean
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Images")
    lngLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    aInData = ws.Range("A1:A" & lngLastRow)
    lngLastRow = 1
    For lngLoop1 = LBound(aInData, 1) To UBound(aInData, 1)
        blnFound = False
        strDummy = Left(aInData(lngLoop1, 1), InStrRev(aInData(lngLoop1, 1), "-"))
        For lngLoop2 = 1 To lngLastRow
            If strDummy = aOutData(lngLoop2, 1) Then
                blnFound = True
                aOutData(lngLoop2, 2) = aOutData(lngLoop2, 2) & "|" & aInData(lngLoop1, 1)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next lngLoop2
        If blnFound = False Then
            aOutData(lngLastRow, 1) = strDummy
            aOutData(lngLastRow, 2) = aInData(lngLoop1, 1)
            lngLastRow = lngLastRow + 1
        End If
    Next lngLoop1

    For lngLoop1 = 1 To lngLastRow
        If Len(aOutData(lngLoop1, 2)) > 0 Then
            ws.Cells(lngLoop1, 2) = aOutData(lngLoop1, 2)
        End If
    Next lngLoop1
End Sub
```

Regards,